# calling a table in a SQL error

Tags: mysql

hello  I was working on a sql Query to get the select count, but it says error, when prepraing the consulte, would you mind to help me guys, with this  problem. here is the structure of my tables.

Table structure

```
    categorias Table
------------------------------
idCat(PK)   nombre
------------------------------
1      "category1"
2      "category2"
3      "category3"


subcategorias Table
------------------------------------
idSubcat(PK) nombre   categId(FK)
---------------------------------
  1         "subcat1"     2
  2         "subcat2"     3
  3         "subcat3"     3
```

my query

```
SELECT count(*) valor  
FROM subcategorias 
WHERE categorias.nombre= "category3" 
AND subcategorias.nombre= "subcat1"
```

and my query spected result should be 1 but it says error :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are two separate tables, which do not automatically "know" about each other, so you can't query from one of them (subcategorias), and assume it knows that one of it's value (categId = 3) points to a specific row (with ID = 3) in the other table.

What you need to do is join the two tables in your query:

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM subcategorias
JOIN categorias on subcategorias.CategId = categorias.IdCat
WHERE categorias.nombre= "category3" 
AND subcategorias.nombre= "subcat1"
```

If you try this without the where-clause, you'll see that it "joins" combinations of rows from the tables, based on your condition, which is that the categoryId's should match.

Your WHERE-clause will then effectively query from this resulting "combo-table", and should give you the result you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM categorias, subcategorias
WHERE categorias.nombre= "category3" AND subcategorias.nombre= "subcat1"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do a join with the two tables there. The problem is that you are doing a select from subcategorias with a select that includes data from some other table. Something like this.

```
SELECT count(*) valor  
FROM subcategorias 
INNER JOIN categories ON categorias.nombre= "category3"
WHERE subcategorias.nombre= "subcat1"
```